# net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (react native image resizer)

Tags: react-native, image-resizing, react-native-image

File exist in emulator but react native image resizer cant load the image to resize it in android

It works fine with IOS, but gives only issue with android

Also base64 way of resizing does not work too.

Snapshot
[image]

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No... I didn't..